# How to use media queries in CSS to fix the menu?

Tags: css, media-queries, resolution

MY site: `pkgeek.com`

Resolution: `1024x768`

The menu at the top looks good in this resolution.
If I zoom out there is  no problem at all.
But When I zoom in, it becomes very bad (Just scatter and the last menu come on the next line).

How Can I fix it?

the width can be controlled through media queries like

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
// What style to put to fix that?
}
```

But how to control this menu?

Comment: Consider posting the relevant HTML and CSS from your website, because nobody will have the time to view and analyze your source.

Comment: not a lot to go on... for all I know `display:none`? :P

Answer (score 0):

Despite the borders on every menu element, you could just style every `<li>` element as `display:inline-table`

Comment: I checked through inspect element. I was using inline-block;
I replace to to inline-table and then zoom in but still it was not fixed

Comment: Forgot to add , make your `<ul>` `display:table` and `text-align:center` will make it look nice